# Append Special Characters at the leading end of Crystal Report's Field

Tags: crystal-reports, special-characters, crystal-reports-2008

Am designing a crystal report and at a point am having issue to append special characters at the end of field.

e.g

```
Name                                                 Qty      
____________________________________________________________
Citrus ............................................   10
Sweet Fruit .......................................   20
____________________________________________________________
```

I want to append ... dynamically at the remaining part of the field.
Any body guide me.

Comment: Where do you want to append? can you show an example? As in question I don't see any special characters

Comment: @Siva: "Citrus" and "Sweet Fruit" are database values, and I want to append ....(Dots) to complete the length of text field

Answer (score 1):

The following code will give you a fixed-length string given you are using a fixed-width font:

```
local numbervar totalLength := 20; //Total desired length constant
local numbervar fruitLength := length({Table.Fruit}); //Length of your database field

if fruitLength < totalLength then
 {Table.Fruit} + ReplicateString(".",totalLength-fruitLength)
else {Table.Fruit}
```

Comment: Is total lenght is fixed and will it extend to the end if name character is only '1 character' and if it is '10characters'

Comment: I have tried your code but unfortunately requested requirement is not getting achived.

Comment: @Siva There's nothing complicated going on here. Which part aren't you in agreement with?

Comment: @Siva Try replacing {Table.Fruit} with a hard-coded string like "Apple". The formula will give you a 20-character string. Then try it again with "Tangerine" and it will again give you a 20-character string regardless of the length of the fruit that was input.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a solution that woked for me, posting solution here... implement and let me know.

1. Create formula `@Line`

   ```
   Shared StringVar a;

    a:="................................................................................................................................................................................."
   ```
2. Now create a formula `@Display1` and write your code of `Name` and your logic to print special character.

   ```
   EvaluateAfter({@line});
   Local NumberVar i;
   Local Numbervar j;
   Local Stringvar k;
   Local Stringvar b;
   Shared StringVar a;
   j:=(Length({tablename.Name})+ Length(totext({tablename.qty})));
   for i:=0 to Length(a)- j do
   (
    k:=k+".";
    );
    {tablename.Name}+k;
   ```
3. Now create one more formula `Qty` and place to the right most part of the report.
4. Place `@Display1` to the left most part of the report and extend it to meet the `Qty` formula which is on the right most part of the report..

Comment: There looks like a lot of unnecessary things happening here... What is the point of the shared variable `a` in a separate formula? Or the variable `b`, which is not used at all? And why would you create these strings one character at a time?

Comment: That will append the required special character from the ending point of the name field

Comment: This is a tested one and that worked successfully for me

Comment: I understand that that is the goal here and I don't doubt that this works, but I'm curious as to why you chose to implement it this way.

Comment: Actually to get the dynamuc behaviour with not knowing what would be length of string.. so took the length of text field in report and subtracted the length of string that comes dynamic... and appending the remaining part to the end result by that ensuring it always starts after the end of name filed and ends at one point.

Comment: @Craig until and unless user doesn't have any issue I don't think anybody should have issue with my solution and also I can give the solution I comes to my mind.. I don't expect to follow other people thinking.